# Is it possible to mount iSCSI on multiple machines?

Tags: zfs, iscsi, truenas

I have a freeNAS setup with iSCSI attached to my Windows machine. That servers me great cause I get all the ZFS features and easy reconnecting in Windows - Don't have to mess around with SMB mappings and reconnect issues constantly.

I have tried to search for setting up iSCSI to allow for multiple connections. Generally people say its a bad idea.. but maybe you it can be done with multipath or some other way?

Comment: StarWind support nails it right in the head with their thread here: https://forums.starwindsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1392